# ACF custom fields won't update. What is the reason?

Tags: wordpress

ACF custom fields of a page won't update. When I update the fields a new row get created in the database. ACF won't update the rows where the field exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this on a WP Engine hosted site.
Wordpress 5.7.1
Advanced Custom Fields PRO 5.9.5

I found it to be related to a custom plugin that was using the save_post hook. Try disabling other plugins to isolate which is preventing the changes from being saved.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I figured another method out. Whatever the reason, I didn't have time to solve it. So, what I did was to create custom posts with CPT UI and include the same values to those posts.